# Select an element inside an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Here is my DOM:

```
<div class="a">
    <div class="b">b</div>
    <div class="c">c</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('div.a').on('click',function(){
     // ....add a div append to div.a
});
$('div.b').on('click',function(){
     //....edit the content of element
});
```

Clicking `div.a` will add another `div` (d,e,f,etc.) inside `div.a`. Clicking `div.b`, `div.c` or other `div` inside will edit the content of `div.b`. How can I achieve this?

If I click `div.b` it will load the event of `div.a` but not `div.b`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [event.stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation):

```
$('div.b').on('click',function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
   //...
});
```

> Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

Comment: Should add: Since the parent div has an onClick event the child will inherit that event. So if you add an onClick on a child you need to first tell the parent not to launch it's onClick event.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal the jsfiddle demonstrates what I just said. Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.""like you just quoted.

Comment: sorry I'm not getting you. But the quote is right as it stops bubbling up the DOM tree, when you click on b then a's click won't get triggered as is using stopPropagation....

Comment: @BhojendraNepal I might have badly expressed myself but that is what I meant.